# <select multiple> and enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: html, asp-classic, multipartform-data, enctype

I wonder if it is possible to use both enctype="multipart/form-data" and a select multiple. Here is the drill:

I have this html file (test.html):

```
<form action="action.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">

    <select multiple name="prof">

        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Ok" name="Ok">  

</form>
```

When I select any of those options on my list, my action page doesn't show anything (action.asp):

```
<%

dim prof

prof = request.form("prof")

response.write prof 

%>
```

But if I remove the enctype="multipart/form-data" in test.html, then it works.

The problem is that I am using an asp upload file component that requires this enctype="multipart/form-data". Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using the ASPUpload component, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615143/1682881

Comment: That is a nice solution indeed, but I'm not using the ASPUpload component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using enctype="multipart/form-data" it must be because you are uploading a file. if you upload a file you should be using a upload component if you do you could use :

> Set yourUploadComponent =
>   CreateObject("Your.UploadComponentClassString")
>   sFormValue =yourUploadComponent.Form.Item("prof").Value

Comment: If I do like this I get only the first selected item:
prof = Uploader.form("prof")

If I do like you suggested:
    sFormValue = Uploader.Form.Item("prof").Value

I get this error:
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c2'
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Form'

Comment: have you tried using Uploader.form("prof") as an array? 

Uploader.form("prof")(0) ... Uploader.form("prof")(1) ...

Comment: also whats the component your using?

Comment: I will try to use as an array and give you a feedback. It's a component made entirely on ASP made by Jacob "Beezle" Gilley.

Comment: I did a function in JavaScript saving the value of the select multiple into a input type="hidden" and now its working.

Comment: @pcromano Although this answer is right it doesn't explain why. When you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` your telling the server that the data you are posting will be posted as multipart binary data and it is up to you to parse it and retrieve the various multiparts. Classic ASP has a specific method of the Response object for this purpose called `Response.BinaryRead` and `Response.BinaryWrite`. Trying to use `Request.Form` will not work, it doesn't know about multipart data. The most common use for this is uploading file (such as images, documents etc) but not it's only purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a bug on FileUploader class. The mcolFormElem Dictionary variable does not add the name/value pairs if already exist on the collection for the `<select multiple>` element, I have added the below code and working fine.

```
If Not mcolFormElem.Exists(LCase(sInputName)) Then 
                mcolFormElem.Add LCase(sInputName), CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
            else
                dim tempKeyVal
                tempKeyVal=mcolFormElem.item(LCase(sInputName))
                mcolFormElem.Remove(LCase(sInputName))
                mcolFormElem.Add LCase(sInputName), tempKeyVal&","&CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
            end if
```